# Finding Centroid of a curve

Tags: integration, centroid

> $$x=e^t , y = \sqrt{2} t , z= \ e^{-t} ; ~~ ~~ 0\leq t \leq 1$$
>   Find the centroid of this curve.

I know one formula for centroid which is $x = \frac{\int {x dx dy}}{\int dx dy}$ and for y as well, which is for a surface. I don't know any formula for centroid of curve. I've also drawn the curve in mathematica and it is not a closed curve in given boundary. How do we calculate this?

The question is from "Calculus, Adams - Chapter 15.3"

Comment: You  have the right idea. Since it's a curve and not a surface, reduce the dimension in your integrals from $dx dy$ to just $dx$.

Comment: @Théophile them what will be the the denominator? is this just x= $\frac{\int{x dx}}{\int{dx}}$

Comment: Not $dx$, but $ds$.  One dimension down from area is length.

Comment: @user10354138 Should I use s = $\sqrt{e^{2t} + 2 t^2 + e^{-2t}}$ and then differentiate it?

Comment: Yes, I meant $ds$, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate centroid of a curve, first we compute the $\mathrm{d}s$:
$$\mathrm{d}s = \sqrt{x^\prime(t)^2+y^\prime(t)^2+z^\prime(t)^2}=\sqrt{e^{2t}+2+ e^{-2t}}$$

Now note that $$\int_0^1 \mathrm{d}s = \int_0^1 \sqrt{e^{2t}+2+ e^{-2t}} \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^1 \sqrt{e^{-2t}(e^{4t}+2e^{2t}+1)} \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^1 e^{-t}(e^{2t}+1)\mathrm{d}t$$

$$=\int_0^1 e^t+e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t = e-\frac1e\approx 2.35$$

Then you have

$$\bar{x}=\frac{\int_0^1 e^t(e^t+e^{-t})\mathrm{d}t}{2.35}\approx 1.78$$

$$\bar{y}=\frac{\int_0^1 t(e^t+e^{-t})\mathrm{d}t}{2.35}\approx 0.761$$

$$\bar{z}=\frac{\int_0^1 e^{-t}(e^t+e^{-t})\mathrm{d}t}{2.35}\approx 0.609$$

Comment: A problem. isn't $y' = \sqrt{2}$  ? I think If we use $y' = 2$ it will be elementary. isn't it?

Comment: The formula for centroid is $\bar{y} = \frac{\int_a^b y\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}s}{\int_a^b\mathrm{d}s}$. Here $y:=t\sqrt{2}$. We do not differentiate $y$.

Comment: I meant in the $ds$. you wrote y'. y' is $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @amirna Yes you are absolutely correct. I have fixed my mistake. The integrals are now more manageable.